# Migration of XML functionality from Oracle to DB2 LUW (ver 9.7 on AIX)

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, db2, procedure

We are trying to migrate a set of Oracle PL/SQL's to DB2. We have set the Oracle compatibility vector in the db2 configuration parameters, but we are facing issues in instances where an xml file is being read in the Oracle PL/SQL code, eg:-
 `v_parser dbms_xmlparser.Parser;`
`v_doc dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;` 
 `v_nl dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList;`
`v_n dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;` 
`v_parser := dbms_xmlparser.newParser;`

The above sort of code does not compile in a db2 Stored Procedure, throwing error for "dbms_xmlparser" (Object not found). As per my understanding, the best approach would be to develop an equivalent code using pureXML to load the xml file into a temporay or staging table and read it from that table. Is it possible to federate on an xml file and use it as an alias directly?
 All thoughts/inputs are welcome.

Ashwin Pande and Sandeep Pandit

Comment: Can anybody tell what are the equivalent functions in DB2 to perform this (v_parser dbms_xmlparser.Parser; v_doc dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument; v_nl dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList; v_n dbms_xmldom.DOMNode; v_parser := dbms_xmlparser.newParser;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XMLTABLE` function in SQL/XML is capable of shredding an XML document into a multi-row relational expression without requiring a temporary table. To pull a single value out of an XML document, you may decide to use the `XMLQUERY` function instead. Check out some of IBM's examples in the DB2 Knowledge Center for your DB2 version, or on IBM developerWorks. The DB2 pureXML Cookbook published by IBM Press is another helpful resource.